# Filter according to ICollection in EF core

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Having the following database schema:

- objects1

  - id
  - name
- objects2

  - id
  - object1_id

Which translates to the following:

```
public class Objects1
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string ICollection<Objects2> Object2List {get; set;}
};

public class Objects2
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Objects1 Object1 {get; set;}
};
```

How can I filter objects1 rows according to objects2 values?

Something like:

```
mydb.Objects1.Where(o1 => o1.Object2List.Any(o2.Name.Contains("bla")))
```

But this gives a runtime exception.

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Luticate2.Auth.DataAccess.Models.LuGroups]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Luticate2.Auth.DataAccess.Models.LuGroups]' of method 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Luticate2.Auth.DataAccess.Models.LuGroups] ThenBy[LuGroups,Guid](System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable`1[Luticate2.Auth.DataAccess.Models.LuGroups], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Luticate2.Auth.DataAccess.Models.LuGroups,System.Guid]])'
Parameter name: arg0

Comment: Do you use `OrderBy` somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so, that's why I don't understand the `ThenBy`. I'll make a simpler test case to check that

Comment: Okay, my bad, I had a default ordering on `id`. I made a simple test, and it seems to work. The problem seems to come from my code, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, on a very simple test, everything works, but on my case, I'm generating the `OrderBy` and `ThenBy` calls dynamically at runtime, so I need to call `OrderBy` or `ThenBy` depending on if the `IQueryable` is in fact a `IOrderedQueryable`.

Strangely, if calling something like `queryable.Where(o1 => o1.Object2List.Any(o2.Name.Contains("bla")))` before ordering, `var ordered = queryable as IOrderedQueryable<TModel>;` is not null, but the call to `ThenBy` fails. I fixed the problem by ordering before filtering.